# Injecting script into iframe before load in node-webkit

Tags: iframe, node-webkit

I'm Trying to make a simple web browser in node-webkit, to polyfill features that Chromium doesn't support yet (time element, etc). I have had success in listening for the iframe.onload event and then appending a script tag with the polyfills, but this still means that features that I've polyfilled won't be detected by Modernizr or other feature detention.

I've tried loading the page using the http node module, appending a script tag and then turning the page source into a data URI for the frame but data uris essentially turn external pages into static html with no scripting, which renders many web pages unusable.

Also, loading a page through node's http module is proving extremely slow compared to loading through an iframe.

So, is there any other way? Ideally I run a script in the iframe before any other scripts are run.

Yes, I am using nwfaketop and nwdisable on the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'document-start' event should be helpful. See https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window#document-start

See also Window.eval() in https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window#windowevalframe-script